# Workload ID wasm-tools isn't supported on this platform

Tags: .net, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

I'm attempting to install wasm-tools on my Windows 11 Pro development machine. I have VS 2022 installed with the latest updates as well as .NET 8.0.100. No matter what I do, I cannot get these tools installed. I keep getting the error message seen below.

`Workload ID wasm-tools isn't supported on this platform.`